# How to set DevExress XtraGridControl Keyfieldname and use it in code behind

Tags: c#, winforms, xtragrid

I am developing Windows based App and in one of my forms I have DevExpress XtraGrid Control with CheckBox column and Name Column, so users can check the subjects they want and Save them.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

First of all I want to know how to set KeyFieldName (like in Aspx GridView) of GridControl, because I couldn't find it in properties.
Second, when my users select some rows and click Add button, I would like to get all the selected rows' by KeyField into XML and save it to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privet! Try this:

```
DataRow row = gridView2.GetDataRow(gridView2.FocusedRowHandle);
```

And look here: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753

```
for(int i = view.SelectedRowsCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int row = view.GetSelectedRows()[i];
    // your code here
}
```

or export selection, look here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E4352.aspx

Here is the sample:
**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("table1");
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
            dt.Columns.Add("CHECK", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
            dt.Columns.Add("DAY");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {i, false, "Option " + i});
            gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extract checked rows
        /// </summary>
        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoEdit1.Text = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var row in ((DataTable)gridControl1.DataSource).AsEnumerable().Where(row => (bool)row["CHECK"]))
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}\r\n", row["ID"], row["CHECK"], row["DAY"]));
            memoEdit1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extract selected rows
        /// </summary>
        private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoEdit1.Text = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (int rowIndex in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
            {
                DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(rowIndex);
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}\r\n", row["ID"], row["CHECK"], row["DAY"]));
            }
            memoEdit1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;  
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region designer

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.gridControl1 = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl();
            this.gridView1 = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView();
            this.gridColumn1 = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn();
            this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1 = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
            this.gridColumn2 = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn();
            this.simpleButton1 = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton();
            this.simpleButton2 = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton();
            this.memoEdit1 = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.MemoEdit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.gridControl1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.gridView1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.memoEdit1.Properties)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // gridControl1
            // 
            this.gridControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.gridControl1.MainView = this.gridView1;
            this.gridControl1.Name = "gridControl1";
            this.gridControl1.RepositoryItems.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem[] {
            this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1});
            this.gridControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(350, 329);
            this.gridControl1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.gridControl1.ViewCollection.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView[] {
            this.gridView1});
            // 
            // gridView1
            // 
            this.gridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn[] {
            this.gridColumn1,
            this.gridColumn2});
            this.gridView1.GridControl = this.gridControl1;
            this.gridView1.Name = "gridView1";
            this.gridView1.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;
            // 
            // gridColumn1
            // 
            this.gridColumn1.Caption = "gridColumn1";
            this.gridColumn1.ColumnEdit = this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
            this.gridColumn1.FieldName = "CHECK";
            this.gridColumn1.Name = "gridColumn1";
            this.gridColumn1.Visible = true;
            this.gridColumn1.VisibleIndex = 0;
            // 
            // repositoryItemCheckEdit1
            // 
            this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1.AutoHeight = false;
            this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Name = "repositoryItemCheckEdit1";
            // 
            // gridColumn2
            // 
            this.gridColumn2.Caption = "gridColumn2";
            this.gridColumn2.FieldName = "DAY";
            this.gridColumn2.Name = "gridColumn2";
            this.gridColumn2.Visible = true;
            this.gridColumn2.VisibleIndex = 1;
            // 
            // simpleButton1
            // 
            this.simpleButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(369, 12);
            this.simpleButton1.Name = "simpleButton1";
            this.simpleButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.simpleButton1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.simpleButton1.Text = "Checked >>";
            this.simpleButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton1_Click);
            // 
            // simpleButton2
            // 
            this.simpleButton2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(369, 41);
            this.simpleButton2.Name = "simpleButton2";
            this.simpleButton2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.simpleButton2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.simpleButton2.Text = "Selected >>";
            this.simpleButton2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton2_Click);
            // 
            // memoEdit1
            // 
            this.memoEdit1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(450, 11);
            this.memoEdit1.Name = "memoEdit1";
            this.memoEdit1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(299, 331);
            this.memoEdit1.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(964, 665);
            this.Controls.Add(this.memoEdit1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.simpleButton2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.simpleButton1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.gridControl1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.gridControl1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.gridView1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.memoEdit1.Properties)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        #endregion

        private DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl gridControl1;
        private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView1;
        private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn gridColumn1;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
        private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn gridColumn2;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton simpleButton1;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton simpleButton2;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.MemoEdit memoEdit1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spasibo for response. How can I get a collection of selected ID's if Users select multiple rows. In Asp.Net I've used this code: `         System.Collections.Generic.List<object> keyValues = grdClasses.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID");
  `

Comment: I now have not installed devexpress, but try to help you. If all else fails, I will install devexpress. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using DevExpress v2010 vol1

Comment: See changes in the response. If there are any questions, write

Comment: @Shohin: +1 for `Privet` and `Spasibo`. You guys made my day!

Comment: @BorisGappov Thank you very much. My issue regarding saving Data is solved. But I have one problem left with my XtraGridControl. When I select multiple rows as it is shown in attached picture, it is saving only single focused Row. How can I make it to save all the selected Rows?

Comment: Try to set gridView1.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;

Comment: I did Enabled MultiSelect to True. I can select multiple Rows, but when I try to save, it saves only focused Row's value.

Comment: Please look what returns gridView1.GetSelectedRows() method. How do you save values?

Comment: Finally I fixed it. I just had to make GridView and DataTable column names the same. @BorisGappov spasibo za pomosh'.